# Unable to FindControl() in ListView ItemEditing

Tags: asp.net, listview, listviewitem, findcontrol

I have a ListView in an ASP.NET web application. When a user clicks the edit button, I want textfields to pop up that are dependent on certain values of the item. However, I can't seem to find any controls inside of my ListView1_ItemEditing() function.

I have read the Microsoft documentation and various help threads on the internet, but their suggestions do not appear to work for me. This is generally what I see:

```
ListViewItem item = ProductsListView.Items[e.NewEditIndex];
Label dateLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("DiscontinuedDateLabel");
```

For the sake of simplicity I just want to be able to select a label in ListView1_ItemEditing(). This is the code in ListView1_ItemEditing():

```
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataBind(); //not sure if this does anything
    ListViewItem item = ListView1.Items[e.NewEditIndex];
    Label debugLabel = (Label)item.FindControl("label_editing");
    debugLabel.Text = "Works";
}
```

Here is the ASP

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="label_editing" runat="server" Text="hello world"></asp:Label>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

When debugging, item and debugLabel are both NULL.

UPDATE: I resolved this issue by moving my logic to ItemDataBound and then checking if my tr (containing textboxes) was in that particular data item. Code below:

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Control tr_verizon = e.Item.FindControl("tr_verizonEdit");
            Control tr_att = e.Item.FindControl("tr_attEdit");
            if (tr_verizon != null)
            {
                //Control tb_meid = e.Item.FindControl("TextBox_Meid");
                Label lbl_carrierId = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lbl_carrierId");
                if (lbl_carrierId == null)
                {
                    Message.Text = "lbl_carrierId is null!";
                }
                else if (lbl_carrierId.Text.Equals(""))
                {
                    Message.Text = "lbl_carrierId is empty!";
                }
                else
                {
                    string recordId = lbl_carrierId.Text;

                    if (tr_verizon != null && tr_att != null)
                    {
                        if (lbl_carrierId.Text.Equals("1"))
                        {
                            tr_verizon.Visible = false;
                            tr_att.Visible = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            tr_verizon.Visible = true;
                            tr_att.Visible = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ItemEditing` event is raised when an item's Edit button is clicked, but before the ListView item is put in edit mode. Therefore controls in `EditItemTemplate` are not available at this time.

[More Info and example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.itemediting.aspx)

Comment: Alright, thank you for your response. What do you recommend is the best approach to solve the problem I have? I am using a SQLDataSource to get a list of entries from SQL Server. Then, if a user wants to edit the entry, I want to have an additional <tr> display based on what the datasource provided for that row (specifically, if IMEI is not NULL, I want to display an ATT control set. If the MEID is not NULL, I want to display a Verizon control set). I am relatively new to ASP.NET so sometimes the hardest thing for me is knowing what things to investigate. Thank you.

Comment: Nevermind, another programmer helped me resolve this issue. I'll post the solution in the OP for anyone else who may have a similar issue in the future.

Comment: This doesn't provide a solution. Just an explaination.

Answer (score 2):

You should do the DataBind() first, like this:

```
    ListView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    ListView1_BindData(); // a function that get the DataSource and then ListView1.DataBind()
```

// Now find the control as you did before

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried casting the `sender` object instead of trying to access your ListViewItem by index?

```
protected void ListView1_ItemEditing(Object sender, ListViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    var item = sender as ListViewItem;
    var debugLabel = item.FindControl("label_editing") as Label;
    debugLabel.Text = "Works";
}
```

Comment: That means `item` is null. I think you might want to have a look a Kaf's answer.